# how to find a users password if i have nt authority

Tags: windows

I have logged onto a machine and opened a terminal with myself as nt authority\system. I wish to switch to a user. can I grab their password and how would I do that. (not really a windows person)

Answer (score 2):

> can I grab their password and

No, you cannot, as the password is *not stored* in the first place – only a hash is.

With sufficient rights, however (technically Administrator is enough) you can get access to the account database (the `SAM` registry file) and obtain the *NT hash* of the password. The hash can be either attempted to crack in order to obtain the real password, or used for NTLM authentication over the network. The process of dumping SAM is well-documented in many places.

If the user is currently *logged in,* however, you can (or at least could) switch your console to their existing session using `tscon` – having SYSTEM privileges bypasses the requirement to provide a password for that.

Answer (score 0):

Even an administrator cannot grab another user's password.
Windows for login stores the password as a hash, not as plain text.
The few cases where the plain password is stored are not accessible
even for an administrator.

However, an administrator can **reset** a user's password.
This has serious implications if the user has used the
[Encrypted File System (EFS)](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/fileio/file-encryption),
in that he will lose access to his encrypted data.

If you're sure that the user has not used EFS, you may reset his password
by using the GUI or the Command Prompt.

The following command-lines run with administrator permission will
reset/change a user's password:

```
net user USERNAME NEWPASS
net user "USER NAME" NEWPASS
```